# difference between python2 and python3 in terms of multiprocessing?

Tags: multiprocessing, pytorch

So I had a paragraph of code "train.py" that goes like

```
    do something
    print('log something...')
    do something else
```

and I used pytorch's multiprocessing toolbox

```
    import torch.multiprocessing as mp
```

to execute multithreads of "train.py", however, the print function works well under python3, but not python2. Why?

Comment: As a first step for analysing the problem I would replace print() with sys.stdout.write(). The technical details of "print" are very different between python2 and 3.

Answer (score 0):

so in python 2 multiprocessing, new process creation is by default fork() method and forking a multithreaded process could be problematic.

Pytorch uses multithreaded process and to do it safely they use the below-mentioned functionality of python 3

```js
import multiprocessing as mp

def foo(q):
    q.put('hello')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mp.set_start_method('spawn')
```

Note that above snippet will only work with python 3.  They use method "set_start_method" and ask python interpreter to start a new process by using 'spawn' rather than 'fork'

As I said the above method only works in python 3's multiprocessing module and because python 2's multiprocessing module does not have "**set_start_method**",  your code

```js
import torch.multiprocessing as mp
```

might not work as expected. It does not give you an error but the results of the computation are not reliable

Answer (score 0):

Although there are more differences, one of the main differences is the use of the `with` statement. An easy way to understand the difference is to see how to use multiprocessing using `with` for both Python 2 and Python 3. If you add (in Python 2 or 3):

```py
# For python 2/3 compatibility, define pool context manager
# to support the 'with' statement in Python 2
if sys.version_info[0] == 2:
    from contextlib import contextmanager
    @contextmanager
    def multiprocessing_context(*args, **kwargs):
        pool = multiprocessing.Pool(*args, **kwargs)
        yield pool
        pool.terminate()
else:
    multiprocessing_context = multiprocessing.Pool
```

After that, you can use multiprocessing the regular Python 3 way, regardless of which version of Python you are using. For example:

```
def _function_to_run_for_each(x):
       return x.lower()
with multiprocessing_context(processes=3) as pool:
    results = pool.map(_function_to_run_for_each, ['Bob', 'Sue', 'Tim'])    print(results)
```

will work in Python 2 or Python 3.